# Discover files in C++

Tags: c++

How can I find a list of files with specific extensions in C ++ and all windows driver

For example in python :

```
import os
```

def discoverFiles(startpath):
    extensions = [
        'rar','pdf','mp3'
    ]

```
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath):
    for i in files:
        absolute_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, i))
        ext = absolute_path.split('.')[-1]
        if ext in extensions:
            yield absolute_path
```

x = discoverFiles('/')
for i in x:
    print i
[Test my script for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkU5d.png)

Please help me with windows api code or C++ internal library

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved in a cross-platform manor using the standard library file_system component in C++17 and above: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem.  Before that file_system implementations are available via Boost (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) or the file system technical specification (in the std::experimental namespace)

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

auto discoverFiles(fs::path start_path)
{
    std::vector<std::string> extensions = { ".rar", ".pdf", ".mp3" };
    std::vector<std::string> files;
    for (const auto& path : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(start_path))
    {
        if (std::find(extensions.begin(), extensions.end(), path.path().extension()) != extensions.end())
        {
            files.push_back(path.path().string());
        }
    }
    return files;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto files = discoverFiles( fs::current_path().root_path() );
    std::copy(files.begin(), files.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, 
"\n"));
}
```

A few points to note are that this differs from your python implementation by not having access to the yield keyword.  As such results are calculated up front instead of being deferred to their point of use like in Python, which can have an impact on memory usage and performance.  This may change in the future once C++ get access to co-routines and can then implement yield semantics in the language (discussion are on going for how it could be included in C++20, but its yet to be seen if it will make it into this release of the language)

Additionally this was tested on Windows, which did not like scanning recursively from the root of a drive and raised an access exception.  However specifying any folder below the root caused it to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows you can use [`FindFirstFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea).

On *nix it's [`glob()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html).  Which [also exists in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html), and is probably a better fit for this problem than the original Python code in the question.